# Does Pillai Lokacharya’s commentary on the Gadya Trayam still exist?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, translation-request, reference-request, thenkalai

The Sri Vaishnava sect has two sub-sects, Thenkalai and Vadakalai. Vadakalais follow the teachings of Vedanta Desikan, whereas Thenkalais follow the teachings of Pillai Lokacharya.  My question is about Pillai Lokacharya.  His most famous works are the Ashtadasa Rahasyas, eighteen philosophical works on Sri Vaishnavism in general and the Rahasya Traya or three secrets of Sri Vaishnavism in particular.  But I’m interested in another work of Pillai Lokacharya, the Gadyatraya Vyakhyanam.

For those who don’t know, the Gadya Trayam refers to three prose hymns, the Sharanagati Gadyam, the Sri Ranga Gadyam and the Vaikuntha Gadyam, composed by the famous Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya.  They’re hymns to Vishnu and Lakshmi, and they discuss, among other things, the nature of Sharanagati and Vishnu’s highest abode of Paramapadam.  Now Pillai Lokacharya wrote a Vyakhyanam or commentary on Ramanujacharya’s Gadya Trayam.  My question is, does this commentary still exist?

I can’t seem to find it, either in its original language (which is either Sanskrit or Tamil, I don’t know which), or in translation.

Comment: Why the downvote?